Python bytes to dict with Node.js PSON-like pairs
I was rewriting some decode JS functions in python for base 64 strings from one web game and encountered this one:
        const stateDecode = function(rawdata) {
            let ISpsonpair = new PSON.StaticPair(["physics", "shapes", "fixtures", "bodies", "bro", "joints", "ppm", "lights", "spawns", "lasers", "capZones", "type", "w", "h", "c", "a", "v", "l", "s", "sh", "fr", "re", "de", "sn", "fc", "fm", "f", "d", "n", "bg", "lv", "av", "ld", "ad", "fr", "bu", "cf", "rv", "p", "d", "bf", "ba", "bb", "aa", "ab", "axa", "dr", "em", "mmt", "mms", "ms", "ut", "lt", "New body", "Box Shape", "Circle Shape", "Polygon Shape", "EdgeChain Shape", "priority", "Light", "Laser", "Cap Zone", "BG Shape", "Background Layer", "Rotate Joint", "Slider Joint", "Rod Joint", "Gear Joint", 65535, 16777215]);
            rawdata_caseflipped = "";
            for (i = 0; i < rawdata.length; i++) {
                if (i <= 100 && rawdata.charAt(i) === rawdata.charAt(i).toLowerCase()) {
                    rawdata_caseflipped += rawdata.charAt(i).toUpperCase();
                } else if (i <= 100 && rawdata.charAt(i) === rawdata.charAt(i).toUpperCase()) {
                    rawdata_caseflipped += rawdata.charAt(i).toLowerCase();
                } else {
                    rawdata_caseflipped += rawdata.charAt(i);
                }
            }
            data_deLZd = LZString.decompressFromEncodedURIComponent(rawdata_caseflipped);
            databuffer = bytebuffer.fromBase64(data_deLZd);
            data = ISpsonpair.decode(databuffer.buffer);
            return data;
        }

It requires Node.js PSON that has no alternative in python. Are there some python libs that could do the same or rewriting pson in python (or even parsing bytes myself) is the only way? Also data is encoded not in JSON format and can't be decoded into utf-8 or utf-16.
In Python I already have this, so I only need to decode it from bytes to python dict:
import base64
from lzstring import LZString


def decode_state(state: str):
    new_state = ""

    for i in range(len(state)):
        if i <= 100 and state[i].islower():
            new_state += state[i].upper()
        elif i <= 100 and state[i].isupper():
            new_state += state[i].lower()
        else:
            new_state += state[i]

    from_uri = LZString.decompressFromEncodedURIComponent(new_state)
    return base64.b64decode(from_uri)


init_state = "jWCW9ahaqG6GsGbWmycybYaVyb3aeIGuqdDSObtabqhSbbgGstIJbOdebwafqUWgeZCatrOSauUWaMiaciqAaoZqawanqG6acWk45irj2lIAzBpQ0DxgDZmKSiuaUAzc9mmDOrDSrTmWcAAwAWjCsAC40JLzuuACefgDOAIYA4pYA1jSOrgBGyRr+LryBuACyIjSiaYKOAJZIUDy8EvIAiuUIaYkAGmgAVnDJAGoaEnlYtjSg2SqZSBJTKrxgfILyvSrSvOvSLZwbREi8dNIbrrpoAE4QRILJYCBEcgC2okr32ACq9-4E9wDsRho6hEIDkYgwiTAABkUFAiEooWIapQlCVWLY0A0lAB5HD0Oi2eyNVBEGILJYrNYbKB7Ha0g5HGgnaRnBSXa63e6PGgvN4gT7fX4gAFAuj3MEVCHQ2G2REVXqJLJQJAgemHY7nK43IXcp5oBAsVgxLG47D4woksmqxbLKIoeRyLr0IUi4HgyEwrFy0QKpUqtWM2RsrWCHXPfWG422U3m4koUmgPYUu0OmhOl2At2Sj0yhFiX2kf37dVMzUcsM8iNsKM4vEEviWxM2lb2x3O-6ZsXZ6Ve-OKwvW6QMjXB8tc8MG6smusW+NWpO2wSttPt4Wd8qiKWe2V9v2D4el0fa8eVydG6dm+u8RvW5NL1Ppjuijdb3PegvK-cloOKEMVvVnjWMZXjeC4tg+q6ul2m45r28r9p+AYjr+Y4PBOkYXrGDZzk2d7Lo+a7Pu6PY7vBe5IYeKHHmhp4YdGM5xgmt6LvhkHrsRUIzAc8wgBcKgEK4Ki4BQXQqPQRBBk8gTYBAtiDLJSgwApiRidI2J-C0GAqKI0LPOwMmRNkTyOFafECZxwmieJknSQp8m2EptgqfQakaVpOlQnpBl8EZJmgGZ2B7JZYkSc8tlyQpjlKM5rmadpuk8vp1w+cZpn8dg0zBdZYUyRFDnKap6lxR5XnJbwvlpQJ6xZaFPLhUo9mKQVLlFe5CVPElhmpf56V8TVNm5Q1kXKQ4DpZOV8jSHEFQAK6BNKvDwpw0i2EgwCOEoNSyXwgSTdgYAaF0+0aNkx20GANSOAAHmIM1IBQnmJQ6NwANIHSU2IHRgACMF1QvtFRPPdJysI4IMSSoyQyPFOiJd55Xdbx-FXSc-U5XZw1OaNEDjdkk3TaIc0LUtxBKGtG1bY0u0sgdR0HadB3nZdN2zfdj0dc9ghvRoJRfBoP1-QDohAxQINgyorAQ1DJw6bDHXwxVPUEFdmUiSFA0Y-lWO2GNPn47d80wotSicMkq3rZt21FHttPHQzGhM9dt1s3pnPcyUkL879NT-WIIti+DJzSzDpVdX5SPK1paN1YNjVRYk2O4-rs2GygxucLg8Lk5bVM24ddtnSIzPOw9rscu74Be4LfvAxL4uS0H0Oy6HKXh2ZMQWWr2Ux5rTXa0ousTVNBvEybojmxTVvU8ddMnYXF1O6zpdPeX71PF93u+4Dteg4HkNN2Acuda3lUxNVXe1VJseY9Fid68PKej5wL1ZxblM7Xns-247LOEy7K+vXevEDe1dt6izrnvYOzc4ZlUVhHGIfwhIXw1nlPut8dY43vgTImRslolAnjnD+NN8703nsXJe7N2Bu3enEKuPshb+wgRLKWB8j4K0RmZDAQVkHo1QfHO+Q9sGp3TmgV+k9c7EK-mQxef9l4c1XjzN4dCt7Cx3vXFhMtD4twRiZe4FAjC4EcIIegF1siAiILQGgUBRC8BKPCIkSgyAMScA4NIiZHTqENOwBwJRMFRCMG0P2lB6iFF2hcNOjRsgoD+NNVgSgXDkBaJo3A2kiApOkFotMgSaiBI0DCAgO48lIOwC9D4yQrojGSIEA4Tx-AgBKFkAgu1RAIEEGASxYoWCDCBk8SwvQ2Z1xmokKSIzdoIAoGARSKgMAlBmXMkowAShgAumKGoBAi5QjiDUCg000BPC6CgEoSwaB7K6EYaQLNTkYFwJc-ZGAoS3K6BgCgjyuFXVAOsUQDI1B0BgAQAgXxQQiA0FBYFYIaicBlKQMgh4ugZHuBgX+vQJCHikkoHABBjnCzIDcExFQiDZCII9Loni2DeIwRtJ4OM7CYKgCimWTJ+I3BaFyJlZMWAIBaLkVgQQnjABiNkAAyjQaacAel9J+ccSAsBAgxESDANABkGoqHYAAR0CKMp4ZA0jLJOn8WZBq5n+AwGAMSjL6BJJCpxExj0UCBCMdgW19r7qwztY4Bprr7V2M9e6zJbq0AUHwLwWwfLHUADY6BQBmi0DQtJBKZ2-EJQS49QyGniTwRJzJA3hgKLnXogJdhhTDR854wAZrJXILC+FxcajZBuuAFmPLXEOEFcADQJwlhKEFV9CABBBhQHiIILoYqzGiFCC5egIAXrJFEUgXAaRJxiqQL09YwImTSpgLK+VirrjKrVRqg9WqdX031fMo1JqzUnAtVeolYkEpusEI6uQbqXXPq9Y4H13q32+p9QGoNIacBQgjVYwQLRBjMnjQeVGyaKCprYOm6FlqVpyzQLmj++aaBcqLSWnkZaK0wqDHCouTta31rAI23NSgMi2Fbe2m0Xae19oHUOkdRgx0TqnTOg487F3itXXQdd0BN1yoVUqwYKr1Wau1bq7Ip7DWzONaa-EV7LXiWtfe+1j6nWOFfTQN1Hrv1fr016v19q-0RKUKGoDkbo2WAg6jKDSaZawd+PBhJZAkPZsrGh62GGWi9GwyAALuHy0kErYR6tJG633HI4aSj1Gu1to7ZM7t-MIDJFYMx4dTxR3jukJO6ds6eP0F4BoXoZioDsBeo05prT2kCZEF0vjAzQZDM1WMiZUyz0GsWcsmoqz1l-S2TslgpzDnHNOec15NzRt3IebNp5LyFtvI+akw4kqCBpFXGCEF7ENDgshQ0aFVaQSIvzPSsK6LsAEDeoDHFxixAEqJR48oHBE6WepRQWl9LtKMuIKB1lpMkAcq5Rl3l-KhU0BNTQJdK7JWCZlSJnd8JxP7qk8evV8nz1KfNap29Nrv1ae-bp-TH7DNpMM6Zxw5ng2WcA8BmggqWhPHs0JRzuAYNwbie5zzKGfO7T8xgQLwW+WheOxF4jN1SMxYo82mjSX6OpaF0xwd2XcsuRKJxorC6-B8fhxkoTW7RO7tR5Jw90mT1Y4Uxe5TYk8fqe00T4zOmvOk8-RT53Szf2Bos1Z4D0gPgtF2KcBziaOfOa5whzNGwvN6n52sAtfxhelrF+Fx0kWpfRYbXFuXiW6OdqV72-tqvWPsekJrwr3Gdcw712ug3iPt1iYk4ejVFvMfdYwIpy9dub0O8J0+53JP33u8-VTmnAHw3HEDzAVnCbAxOe0i5tNPOs189CQnmHNli1BZT-hk7C9M9kdl7YBLtHksMbSxlrLpe8sV643OhdJWysVaqzV+QLS2kdMazQbpy6+ktccDaxb3kHGUmRgGmSt16xWSLkGx9mG12X2XGwWym2WxmxOTm1eSW3QKeU4HeSCzW14ElS0H+XFGBVBQOgOyhTTzTHhRADO3lAuzqiuwIG7Tu1xUe0JWJVJTewpQ+w2i+yVB+1ED+2ZUByzjACgA0FBx5Q1Qh2FQwCf3KyMEqxemFSoCXBwDIEFQdCgCqREwoAZ18GwFYFq0EHOVoS6D+CeAQHazDU4FNUlniA7woG4EmXUFsA0AcC2nhACxIGkECEsGAF6AiFcACJwEwX8MsAgCugiICIgBiFiKiKFyyEiIgH8Bxge1rXMUsUYCgEEEJAcCcUvAcGcBP3cTTG4PJVRD8TMMCTuwoHqHRA-nCWDR8miViSjw82SVSXSUyS6GyVyXyUKU7jwEGBgHYBmkEBgG+ksECB4CaXfzqy-2WR-2awekGWGWANAK60gKWWgIulgM2QuhG2wKQOwJQOwOuVeXm0uKwKuVwNWy+XW2BB+BoCFB23IP2yLkOwzQI3T1OyRUYLRQxRgCCXYPxU4Jey8XeypX4O+0ZWEJOH+xZQeDZWBxoAkEGCMnYBOhgEGB1Rrz-34ylUNyRybzR3Nwx1kyt07xt1x17zvUdwHxfVd2H3J1H293-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-xXQAKANGRAM63AI7wWT2P6xgI2XgIWzOMmwuVQOuMwNeQePwKeMIOBEEDSFEHACBQOk+MoKO2oKIwRUBNRUCGYPADYIewhOewqM-JhM+3hIZSRNENRKBxYExOxNxPxN13wrr0IrJJN2b3RxkzkzPSovpNooJ2dydxZM-WYv01YpM05N93pzoF4FYBaF4tD3n3D0X0jxXxjzX1EsZ3ZhlJw1Fz3wlwPxVJlzVKo2UvP0Lx1L1INNCCNPHP0MMOnOtPnMsOsKXKdNXMNXXKUA9K3J9L9L3MDP9PCOjJPNSLPNSIvLiKvMyNvIsToHoEGCiAKNsCzIJBzLfLzIyuhNsG-JWGLKCTLPHiAtaJAprLczrJhh6KgqbJgoOjgsRAQp4FwDGImKmJmLmKMtnJMs6VWKJMss2Osu2Lst2L6wGxcuOIQIOSOWQM8suLQKuRuKuTuLuT8s+W+WBGdCgEhHCt2yIi+Iuh+PF3+LivOwSuYPXhSrxS+UhPhoLN4NhJpUEIRJEIBwKvEIxKxI6lKoJNhwlUqtJMbxqopLIqpIasNSapUwZNaofWZOdVZKYpH0pz6s4oGpoF4DQBGsQRZDGuOAXxTWFM6LFO8wlMBEFWlKkpCxWo1rktVMUtzzP0V21N1P1KeENJgGNN0InNOuWBnI-xtIXKuodOXMcOcNcIes3K8N3RerCLesPMSOiJHp+riL+qiIBpvOyMGqgCZHsWfOKNsFfLcTho-IRuqJ-JRvqPqBfgxsiVApxvArxobIJsdCJryTbPgpGIpvGMmOmNmPmOMuWKa2ZvWNa1ZoPRsrAIgO6ygKcoOJ5u2T5vcv2QuKuRFowOWwlpwLwOlueLoF6A+HoBqFIIir2yit+P3zoPipsmYOAT1o4PSo3uNoHmpVNoENICEMtpRKIDRKKrtpxOyDxMdtrwE3r2EzdpR1qspPqppN9p7xao0wdQYpDoMxYo5O-XH25OszoBABaF4E4gTrZ34oj1TumuEozrmsFQkqklzuWpktWsLo2uLvVPlxUovyFz2srurtrtNJgEnIJEbvOosMXPbpuq7vdN7u9P7t3MHoPODJHq+riPHqSJHuntMVnoYG+hjsXshpfNcXfMqMLO3rqOxTLPwQPurI6OmtlnxoyUJpbNguvtJtvspofppufvptfqZoso-sAK-qkh-p2P-scu5qG15rcoFvOKFsge8pgd8vgYIMlWdD03QaVrdBVohSoMVNitwa1vwYxQJi1XBINpIZSZNuyvNtyqZStvocKttpKpYbKsJLhxdob2Nx4Y9tby9oEbpL9uEaZLEc6rDs93Yq5K4ujtjrSD4hUbnyTompTsEq6JmpEvQ0BE4GNMkqWvlPVqVLWul2zzMa2osZ2vLv2qrsOpruOrNIbqtNnJbsuvtNGUdJXK8Y3I8L7p3KDIDMCcCKPNSJCcjJHsnvjOvKibvOjvnsFXiccUSdzOhdIZ4K3uRvSdLPqFEWyaxtydxvybPsKYvuKeJtKeJuKTvqpsftpoWI-wZu-3Mv-waasu-vZr-vkwAY6bgK6dOJ6Y8umwGduKGceJlqQY+FEAVo+Mwe+NmZwfoJ9CBMSoxTeCIbSq4Myq2bhJ2d+zyv2YYaOftpObYYqo4aqu4ZIpbyPX4cooeaEbUzoraqDpd1efZPDukcDRUAaDmGxDcH8BKGCJmihF4CoCoFEByRqHoCgDJjyBABCCgGvX5BeiOFDCBBOCgEcD2EkKTCIFrtwDQFmJgEFQBj2VGA+GYHQIkApuDYkAygy3YECC6E3BwHwBCN4HlTqICGCDCBCOSFQFnSeEGCwGu3KDgHiFvcHI2itFElBkoT9OvFwExTEHkECGkAWviFgRgCMBQCHDsCKssBYcsHiGxE4BoGOmsY+DgGGsGDgDxTQCqHkEEGOTgCqF6TSG0iUBZRoECBGGHSoDPbXbgBiDIFSGo1cCQHkA0BmnWlY-Y40C44IDY40CqBAHZjQDJAsApu8J8lBN+gqBQAkEcHiHnoayZGwEcFtAkCeE4D+Ew2U5oAgFwEgAUFEHiBcChDnS+WGUGGRVSHiH3YoH8DEBiEfRoAAF4gA"
print(decode_state(init_state))

